# Can Toric Code have a gapless boundary?

Tags: conformal-field-theory, topological-field-theory, topological-order, anyons

The toric code model is known to have two types of "gapped" boundaries, namely, the rough boundary and the smooth boundary. See, for example, Chap. 4.1 of this beautiful review https://arxiv.org/abs/2205.05565

This fact is consistent with the "higher central charge" condition which is recently suggested in https://www.scipost.org/SciPostPhys.13.3.067?acad_field_slug=all since all the higher central charges obtained from the toric code MTC are equal to 1.

Here, what confuses me is the statement given in Sec. 2.3 of https://www.scipost.org/SciPostPhys.13.3.067?acad_field_slug=all. It says that an Abelian TQFT "admits" a topological boundary condition if and only if the higher central charge condition is satisfied. It sounds like, the toric code may have a gapless boundary even though its higher central charges are all trivial, i.e., equal to 1.

So, is there a gapless boundary consistent with the toric code? If there is one, then what is it?

Comment: According to the answer of https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/34556/counterexamples-to-the-bulk-boundary-correspondence-topological-insulators, the toric code model does not have a gapless bounary excitation. Actually, it seems obvious that the toric code "model" which is familiar does not have one. But what about in the sense of the toric code "phase"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a good question! I couldn't find any reference for this, but here are my thoughts.

What does it mean to have a gapped / gapless boundary? It means that, keeping the bulk intact, we can tweak the Hamiltonian terms near the boundary and see what kind of spectrum it produces, comparing it to the case with no boundaries.

With this definition, it is trivial to see that the toric code (or any state/phase for that matter) can have arbitrarily complicated boundaries. We can always dress the boundary with a CFT, and this will give us "toric code with gapless boundary conditions". **(1)**

This is why it is useful to use the language "admits", as you highlight in your question. The interesting question to ask is "What is the simplest$^\text{a}$ boundary that this phase admits?" Of course we can make the boundary arbitrarily complicated regardless of the bulk phases, but some bulk phases do not allow for "simple" boundaries, and this is what is exotic about Symmetry protected topological phases (SPT) and Topological order (TO). In more technical language, general SPTs and TO induce an anomaly on its boundary, which implies that the boundary must *necessarily* be nontrivial$^\text{b}$.

The solution **(1)** for "does the toric code have a gapless boundary condition?" may be unappealing, so here is a more natural solution. Consider the toric code with smooth boundaries (I am using the convention $B_p = \prod X$). Add a boundary term $\Delta H_{lb} = -\lambda X_{lb}$, where ${lb}$ is summed over the qubits on the smooth edge. Note that $A_{vb}$, where $vb$ are vertices on the smooth boundary has nontrivial commutation with this boundary Hamiltonian. But all the other terms in the toric code Hamiltonian commute among themselves and with these terms so we can set them all to $+1$. Now let us focus on $\Delta H_{lb}$ and $A_{vb}$.

You can see that they have the same algebra as the terms in a transverse field Ising model$^\text{c}$. Therefore, there is a phase transition at $\lambda = 1$. Here, the boundary transitions from smooth to rough boundary (seen by setting $\lambda \to \infty$). The critical point corresponds to 2D Ising CFT on the boundary, and setting $\lambda = 1$ gives you toric code with gapless boundary conditions.

---

$^\text{a}$Simple usually refers to low central charge for gapless boundaries, low GSD for gapped boundaries. Gapped being simpler than gapless.

$^\text{b}$Naively, this is not true for the toric code since it admits a gapped boundary. But the boundary of the toric code is indeed anomalous in a certain sense, described in [Schuster et al](https://arxiv.org/abs/2312.04617).

$^\text{c}$There is a caveat here. Strictly speaking, the effective boundary Hilbert space is the TFIM restricted to $\mathbb{Z}_2$ global symmetry singlet sector, but this does not affect the transition. Indeed, this restriction is related to the boundary anomaly and there is a good review in section II of [Schuster et al](https://arxiv.org/abs/2312.04617).

Comment: So, in short, --- if I understood correctly --- a gapless boundary of TC can be obtained from the transition between the smooth bdry and rough bdry, by adding a local boundary term. And the low energy effective theory for the boundary is the (nonchiral) 2D Ising CFT.

Comment: Yes, that’s one way to get a gapless boundary for the toric code. But it is fine tuned. With fine tuning you can get any kind of gapless state you want on the boundary by adding appropriate Hamiltonian terms.

Comment: Ah, now the meaning of "admit" became more clear to me. The "simplest" boundary is the gapped one, but we can add any term to make the boundary gapless. Hence the TC admits a gapped boundary. Even we can make the boundary chiral by adding.. idk some exotic terms. Thank you for your detailed explanation.

Comment: Ah I should have mentioned — I believe you cannot get chiral edge states. It is believed that you cannot write a local lattice Hamiltonian that gives you a chiral spectrum. I don’t think there is a proof for this except the non interacting fermion case (Nielsen Ninomiya theorem). So whatever chirality your edge state has is tied to the bulk phase. You cannot make the edge chiral by adding local boundary terms.

Comment: You're right. I think if I want a chiral edge state, then maybe I should stack some invertible topological order. But there is no way to get a chiral state by adding local terms.